# What's the function of `MANIFEST.in`?

Tags: python

What's the function of `MANIFEST.in`?

[image]

I found a MANIFEST.in file in a project, and in it there is content:

```
recursive-include *.py
include README.rst
include LICENSE
```

what's the function of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to the other answers: `MANIFEST.in` allows you to control which files are included in your package.

By default, when you actually package up your python code (using, say `python setup.py sdist`) to create a zipped archive for distribution, the packager will only include in the package archive a certain set of files (the python code itself, for example). What if you have a text file (say, a template) or a figure (for your documentation) included in your repository? By default, the packager will not include those files in the archive, and it will be incomplete.

`MANIFEST.in` allows you to override the default, specifying exactly what files you need included in your zip archive for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a manifest template, to specify additional files to distribute in a [python source distribution.](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the content, we know the `MANIFEST.in` is a configure file about `sdist` distribute tool.

From the [MANIFEST.in](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template):

> A MANIFEST.in file can be added in a project to define the list of files to include in the distribution built by the sdist command.
>
> When sdist is run, it will look for the MANIFEST.in file and interpret it to generate the MANIFEST file that contains the list of files that will be included in the package.
>
> This mechanism can be used when the default list of files is not enough.